Sci-fi rom-com movie with time traveller with funny hat
I'm looking for the title of a movie I saw when I was young in the 80s or 90s. I seem to remember strange parts of the plot. I also think the movie might have been British or Australian by origin..not sure though.
The hero is a guy who travels back in time and falls in love. He wears a very strange hat which after a while becomes a fashion statement and more people start to wear it. In the beginning of the movie he is in the future and he has some kind of holographic TV which has an image he walks through (I think it was somebody playing music). When he gets in the present time there is a scene where he gets into a bar/pub and there is a guy on a stool in the middle of the pub playing a guitar and he tries to walk though him as well. At the end of the movie he gives the woman he fell in love with the winning lottery numbers saying: "I just quickly travelled to next week to bring them back for you".
Is there anybody that remembers the movie's name?

Could this be Biggles? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090729/

It's only a hunch but that sounds a lot like a TV play from the 80's which was called 'The Flipside of Dominick Hide'. Hope that helps. From TVTropes:

The Flipside of Dominick Hide is a BBC mini-series from the early 1980s, comprising two 90-minute Made For TV Movies (The Flipside of Dominick Hide and Another Flip For Dominick). The setting is a very bland, possibly dystopic future, Time Travel is possible, and used as a tool to investigate "The Flipside". Dominick Hide is a "Corro", one who records the past. In this case, he is a Corro for London, early 1980s. One day, he decides to land his flying-saucer shaped time travel device and go off on foot, something utterly forbidden, searching for his great-great-great grandfather who is alive in that time. Dominick is utterly taken aback by the vibrancy of the age, compared to the sanitized and automated time he comes from.
The sequel, Another Flip for Dominick, begins with Dominick having been Kicked Upstairs after the end of Flipside, but discovering that another Corro has decided to emulate Dominick's own feat. This time, however, things are not going to end well.
Dominick's hat from the future attracts several comments by the 1980s cast, and by the time Another Flip rolls around, it's become a popular fashion accessory in the 1980s. Possibly inspiring the hats of Dominick's time.


Image of hat: http://img.rp.vhd.me/4532840_l2.jpg
